# Gradients for IE 5-7 (CSS)

Tags: css

Okay so I am currently having problems with gradients in IE 5-7 (It needs to be in there for comptability reasons.)

I have tried using the following code:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#edfdff', endColorstr='#b3e9ef',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

However it does not display the gradient at all and simply displays a white background, the other code I am using for IE9+ and IE10+ works fine and has no issues, the same applies for all other browsers and the code used for them.

Comment: Can you show the full code that you are using this in?

Comment: What exactly would you like to see as the rest of the code actually works fine, it's this exact line that seems to not be able to function.

Comment: @repwhoringpeehaa It's only for a comptability thing :p

Comment: Best would be to add img for this (IE5-6-7) and leave the css for the modern IE browsers

Comment: @NortonTaylor That's what I said. It sucks to be you :) Having to support compatibility for a browser with a market share of [less than 0.5 percent](http://stats.wikimedia.org/wikimedia/squids/SquidReportClients.htm).

Comment: I know it's crazy! and yes, I am going to use a slice :p

Comment: +1 to what Efthimis said - just use an image for older versions of IE. Does the absence of the gradient really break the design? Also, avoid using the IE filters if at all possible- they're a huge drag on performance.

Comment: It's not really up to me what goes and what doesn't as it's not for my own site. This is what they want and it's what I do :P

Comment: If you read the comments, it is not my choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by simple creating a 1 pixel gradient and then repeating it and setting a colour.

```
background: #edfdff url(images/gradient_slice.png) 0 0 x-repeat; /* Old browsers */
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the element that you apply a gradient to must have layout. That is, it must have either a `width`, a `height` or a `position`, otherwise the gradient won't be visible.

So [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prE2y/1/) works in IE6, but [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/prE2y/3/) does not.

By the way, your own answer does not work like the example in your question. First of all, `x-repeat` should be `repeat-x`. And secondly, `GradientType=1` repeats vertically, not horizontally.